# Changing GUI text in android and iOS based on server data

Tags: android, ios

I am a product manager and I want to understand if it is possible to create an application (the question is relevant for both OS) with the following behavior:
When the app launches for the first time, it will call the server and download all the GUI texts.

As part of the response, it will also receive a GUID.

on every next launch it will call the server, and get the GUID. if the GUID is new (doesn't match the current stored GUID) - there was a change in the GUI texts - and it will replace all the GUI texts with the new ones

Is it possible in android and iOS  - and what are the limitations?

Comment: Yeah, why not. Calling a remote api to get response and then change UI accordingly. Seems straightforward.

Comment: Of coz, it is possible to achieve this, but your layout format will be also straight forward